# Cannot read property "0" from undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I can not find the problem

```
function sendSurvey() {
  var recipient = Browser.inputBox("Send Survey", "Enter Recipient Email", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (recipient === 'cancel') return;

  var subject = 'Commuting Survey';

  var scriptUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  if (!scriptUrl) throw new Error( 'You must Deploy as Web App first.' );

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');
  template.scriptUrl = scriptUrl;
  template.serialNumber = getGUID();  // Generate serial number for this response
  var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
  var plainText = 'Please complete this survey online at: ' + scriptUrl;
  html += '<p>Alternatively, you may <A href="' + scriptUrl + '"> complete this survey online.</A>';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, plainText, {htmlBody:html} );

  Browser.msgBox("Survey Sent");
}


function doGet() {
  // Build survey body
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');
  template.scriptUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  template.serialNumber = getGUID();  // Generate serial number for this response
  var app = template.evaluate();
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(_spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  // Assume first sheet collects responses
  var row = [
    new Date(),                     // Timestamp
    e.parameters.serial[0],         // Serial Number
    e.parameters.pytanie1[0],        // Pytanie 1
    e.parameters.pytanie2[0],        // Pytanie 2
  ];
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
  var locked = lock.tryLock(30000);

  if (locked) {
    var rowNum = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
    lock.releaseLock();
    var result = "Response Recorded: \n  "+row.join('\n  ');
  }
  else {
    // Failed to get lock
    result = "System busy, please try again.";
  }

  // Report result of POST, in plain text
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result)
                       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I can not find the problem
Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I can not find the problem
Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I can not find the problem
Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I can not find the problem

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Do you have a question?

Comment: Why do you repeat those two sentences so many times?

Comment: open the [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#opening-the-console) of your browser and see on which line the error happens.

Comment: continuing on comment above, open console, click on the error line number, set a break point.  Other than that, add HTML to this question or otherwise create a jsfiddle for us to look at.

Comment: At first I didn't understand what error you were getting; but after reading "I can not find the problem Cannot read property "0" from undefined" four times, I finally understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of this problems:

- <del>The *ss.getSheets* function returns undefined</del> <sub>(After I've read the documentation I saw that this isn't possible)</sub>
- One of this properties of the *e.parameters* object doesn't exist:

  - *serial*
  - *pytanie1*
  - *pytanie2*

You can add some *console.log*s to see which is the property that doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the comma (,) after **e.parameters.pytanie2[0]**

var row = [

```
new Date(),                     // Timestamp
e.parameters.serial[0],         // Serial Number
e.parameters.pytanie1[0],        // Pytanie 1
e.parameters.pytanie2[0]**,**        // Pytanie 2
```

];